# discord bot installing error through terminal in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, terminal, discord.js

I'm trying to code a Discord bot that can allow people to play chess. I've finished writing the source code and am pretty sure there are no syntax errors in it (I've checked through online `js` checkers). In the terminal, I ran command npm install `node app.js`. I got the following massive message below. As a result, when I did `node app.js` to get my bot online and working with the proper actions it failed.

Error:

```js
    npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.9: express 2.x series is deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.3.0: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see request/request#3142
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o] Error 1
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
    gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
    gyp ERR! command "/Users/daniel/Desktop/discord bot/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/daniel/Desktop/discord bot/node_modules/contextify
    gyp ERR! node -v v14.8.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for express@2.5.9: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"14.8.0","npm":"6.14.7"})
    npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: express@2.5.9
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN discord.js@11.3.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN chessbot@0.0.1 No repository field.
    
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! contextify@0.1.15 install: node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.15 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR! /Users/daniel/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T20_14_21_590Z-debug.log
```

Comment: there was quite a bit of text also between the 1st block of warnings and the "fatal error" message. if that would help, i can send it :)

Comment: I suspect you've a really really old version of discord.js. On the error log, it required node version 0.7 tops. If you check the project github page, it requires 12: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/package.json